# C++ class question: why this "get" method exists

Tags: c++

In my textbook on the chapter introducing classes it gives this example class:

```
class clockType
{
public:
    void setTime(int, int, int);
    void getTime(int&, int&, int&) const;
    void printTIme() const;
    void incrementSeconds();
    void incrementMinutes();
    void incrementHours();
    bool equalTime(const clockType&) const;
private:
    int hr;
    int min;
    int sec;
};
```

The definition of `getTime` is

```
void clockType::getTime(int& hours, int& minutes, int& seconds) const
{
    hours = hr;
    minutes = min;
    seconds = sec;
}
```

What is the purpose of this `getTime` function? It's not returning anything to the caller, so I it doesn't seem useful to the user.
Also, you pass in parameters but then the arguments are *assigned to* the private member variables? That also doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: _"... It's not returning anything to the caller ..."_ of course it does through the reference parameters.

Comment: The reason not using a `return` value here is probably because you should be able to get all 3 relevant time parameters at once which is done by reading the member values into the variables you passed as function arguments

Comment: "Also, you pass in parameters but then the arguments are assigned to the private member variables?" You read the assignment statements backward. The private member variables are assigned to the arguments.

Comment: In C++, a function can return *one thing*. Using "output" parameters (e.g. by reference), the function can have side effects to get around that. Otherwise one would need to return a complex type that had all three of those values.

Comment: @crashmstr - thanks for also explaining the reason behind it!

Comment: I personally would have preferred simple getters for the individual values, though. This way you wouldn't need to provide variables for all values if you are only interested in a single one. Or even provide *both* types of getters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing to your function `getTime` 3 references and these in the getTime function are filled with the private time values. Then once this function is called you will be able to access the time values ​​simply by using the variables you passed by reference. Note that unless you create a Time object that contains these three integers, there is no direct way to return three integers in `C++`.

Answer (score 1):

The function takes reference arguments. Which means it takes the variables' memory addresses and edits them.

```
void example(int& b){
    b=5;
}

int main(){
    int myVar = 0;
    example(myVar);
    std::cout << myVar; // Expected output is 5
}
```